# Writing data from JSON to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I have a list of JSON data where i need to write it to the CSV file.

Can some one help me in writing the optimized code?

Below is the sample input data

```
Original data is big
[
{
'id':123
'name':'john'
'Country':'ABC'
}
{
'id':456
'name':'Mary'
'Country':'DEF'
}
Below is the code that i have written
import csv


headers = ['id','name','num','Country']

f = open('file.csv','w')
wr = csv.writer(f)
wr.writerow(header)


for i in json_response:
     l =[]
     for j in headers:
         if j in json_response:
              l.append(i)
         else:
               l.append("none")
    wr.writerow(data)

f.close()
```

Comment: What's the problem with current approach? Also you have four headers `headers = ['id','name','num','Country']` but sample JSON you have presented has only three key/value pairs, and you have done nothing to handle this.

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

j = [{
'id':123,
'name':'john',
'Country':'ABC',
},
{
'id':456,
'name':'Mary',
'Country':'DEF',
}]

df = pd.json_normalize(j)
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: OP is asking *Can some one help me in writing the optimized code?*, is your answer more efficient than the code snippet presented in the question? If so, you can perform some benchmark and add it to the question.

Comment: @ThePyGuy, Thanks for your comment, I see your point, but "optimized code" is ambiguous for me. Does OP mean performance, or readability, or maintainability? Id argue this answer is optimized, by doing the same but with better readability.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pandas library.
like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(path)
df.to_csv(path_and_name_of_the_new_csv_file, index=None)
```

here is the link:
https://datatofish.com/json-string-to-csv-python/

Comment: Please avoid writing duplicate answer, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68771667/writing-data-from-json-to-csv-file/68771894#68771894) already exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case for a `DictWriter`:

```
import csv

headers = ['id','name','num','Country']

with open('file.csv','w', newline='') as f: # csv expects newline=''
    wr = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
    wr.writeheader()       # the magic of DictWriter

    for data in json_response:
        wr.writerow(data)  # the second point of the magic...
```

Unsure if this will be more efficient, but it is shorter to write, and because of that will be easier to maintain.